# Vim easy way to insert class / method documentation

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way for me to do something like this: `ctrl` + `d` and have it insert a documentation template such as:

```
  /** Creates a person with a given name and age.
    *
    * @param name their name
    * @param age the age of the person to create 
    */
```

Even better, is there a method or plugin that can utilize filetype to insert the appropriate method documentation skeleton?

Comment: Any snippet plugin will help you. I suggest using [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a snippet plugin as follow:

First you need a snippet engine, such as [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) (preferred), [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), or [neosnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim), and a collection of snippet definition, f.i. [vim-snippets](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-snippets).

Then you can modify the `*.snippet` definitions that you can find in the folder where your plugin has been installed with the following:

```
snippet doc
    /** ${1:blabla}
     *
     * @param ${2:first param}
     * @param ${3:second param}
     */${4}
```

If you add that to your `c.snippet` for instance, you will be able to enter `doc<Tab>` (in insert mode) for ant C file, and your template will appear with cursor highlighting "blabla". Taping `<Tab>` again will move the cursor to "first param" and so on until you reach `${4}`.

Comment: Why include `${4}`? Is it to start editing the class itself? I would rather advise to have another snippet for classes, which is for sure already included in vim-snippets.

Comment: `${4}` is just to go after your template once you've finished to edit `${1}` to `${3}`. Then you can press `enter` to go on a new line and write what you have to write, eventually use another snippet for classes or anything. Just saving a bit of time and the pain of going back to normal mode, use `j` and `o` to go edit after the template for instance ;) Not necessarily useful though, I believe it's a matter of preference.